# JavaScript - Converting from string to number adds trailing 0s

Tags: javascript, angularjs, string, type-conversion

So I've been trying to convert a string in the following format to a number:

"20150910095820526"

I've tried unary operators to do it, parseInt, parseFloat, but I always end up with something like this:

1017219000

code attempts:

```
element = parseFloat(element);

element = parseInt(element, 10);

element = ~~element;
```

full code:

```
    $scope.episodes.forEach(function(element) {
      console.log(parseFloat(element));
    }, this);
```

What am I doing wrong? thanks

Comment: paste in the code you tried to use

Comment: The 'number' looks like a date: `2015-09-10 09:58.20526` is this just a coincidence?

Comment: The numbers start with what you would expect in a date, but aren't actually dates

Comment: btw `20150910095820526` cant be represented as number in js

Comment: what is `element`? Paste the full code. For example, I pasted `parseInt("20150910095820526")` into the console and got `20150910095820530` (which is expected due to precision loss with floating point numbers)

Comment: How do you get the result `1017219000`?

Comment: Sorry, that isn't the usual result, will edit

Answer (score 2):

The number you are trying to parse is larger than the max size for a number in javascript (9007199254740991). For this reason, it is best to leave it represented as a string. If you need to perform a mathematical operation on that value you can use a library such as [strint](https://github.com/rauschma/strint).

Strint would let you do something like this:

```
var strint = require("./strint");

strint.add("20150910095820526", "1")

'20150910095820527'
```

Answer (score -2):

Why are you assuming a number that large can be represented in JavaScript?

Read more:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER

Comment: That page lists `9007199254740991` as the biggest number, which is smaller than `20150910095820526`.

Comment: `20150910095820526 > 9007199254740991`. I'm not sure how else to put it :p

Comment: This makes your 'answer' invalid. It doesn't solve OPs problem. You've confirmed that `20150910095820526` is too large to be represented without precision loss.